# Creating string based array introduces random 'b' before string

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, numpy

I'm trying to create a table of basically a list of words. I prefer the table format as eventually it's going to go into excel. However, with my code i keep getting an introduction of the letter 'b' before my string. Any help would be appreciated.

I even tried printing at various stages to see where and why they get introduced. 
Code:

```
from xlwt import Workbook
import numpy as np

wb = Workbook()
Number_Of_Days = int(input('How many days do you want?'))
All_Sheets = np.chararray((Number_Of_Days,1))
All_Sheets = np.chararray(All_Sheets.shape, itemsize = 10)
All_Sheets[:] = ''

print(All_Sheets)

count = 0
while count < Number_Of_Days:
    Sheet_Name = input(print('Enter the name of day', count+1))
    All_Sheets [count,0] = Sheet_Name
    count = count + 1

print(All_Sheets)
```

[Code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbOcx.png)

Comment: This indicates that you are looking at a byte literal, not a string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Comment: @Jeremy Thank you for your quick response. Is there anyway i can make my input a string and note a byte literal in that case?
And will excel show the b '...' when i do put it in? Or will it be ignored?

Comment: This will help with conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string As for what will happen with Excel, I'm honestly not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the `chararray` documentation:

> The `chararray` class exists for backwards compatibility with
>      Numarray, it is not recommended for new development. Starting from numpy
>      1.4, if one needs arrays of strings, it is recommended to use arrays of
>      `dtype` `object_`, `string_` or `unicode_`, and use the free functions
>      in the `numpy.char` module for fast vectorized string operations.

```
In [191]: np.chararray((2,1))
Out[191]: 
chararray([[''],
           [b'\x01']],
          dtype='|S1')
```

The '|S1' dtype means a one character bytestring.  This is the default type in Py2, but in Py3 it is flagged with the `b` character.

A better way of initializing a character array is:

```
In [192]: np.zeros((2,1), dtype='U10')
Out[192]: 
array([[''],
       ['']],
      dtype='<U10')

In [194]: np.zeros((2,1), dtype='S10')
Out[194]: 
array([[b''],
       [b'']],
      dtype='|S10')
```

or even better with a list of strings:

```
In [195]: np.array(['one','two','three'])
Out[195]: 
array(['one', 'two', 'three'],
      dtype='<U5')
```